# Easy deletion of disconnected nodes in Neo4j 2.1.0-M01

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Spent some time figuring out how to easily remove disconnected nodes but I couldn't get  "hold" of them.

```
match (n)-[r]-(m) where r is null delete n
```

obviously doesn't work, neither does

```
match (n) optional match (n)-[r]-(m) where r is null delete r
```

so, what's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT n--()
DELETE n
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea:

```
match (n)                     // match all nodes
with n
optional match (n)-[r]-()     // optionally match relationships
with n, count(r) as c
where c=0                     // filter those having no relationships
delete n                      // get rid of 'em
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps a workaround, but I finally did this

```
match (n)-[r]-(m)
set n.x=1
```

which creates the property for all related nodes n

and then

```
match (n) where n.x is null delete n
```

deletes the loose nodes and

```
match (n) remove n.x
```

to clean up. don't know whether this is good practice, though

Comment: It is quite expensive to do that. Also only works with small graphs.